How does Sean Carroll swap the operators and sign on the index when calculating the observed number of particles in the Unruh Effect?
In Sean Carrol's 2019 version of Spacetime and Geometry: An Introduction to General Relativity, he derives the Unruh Effect. The way that he does this is by calculating the average number of observed particles in Region I of the spacetime diagram. The calculation is performed by using the following operators:

$$\large \hat{b}_k^{(1)}(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sinh\left(\dfrac{\pi\omega}{a}\right)}}\left( e^{\pi \omega/2a} \hat{c}_k^{(1)} + e^{-\pi\omega/2a}\hat{c}_{-k}^{(2)\dagger} \right) \\
\large \hat{b}_k^{(2)}(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sinh\left(\dfrac{\pi\omega}{a}\right)}}\left( e^{\pi \omega/2a} \hat{c}_k^{(2)} + e^{-\pi\omega/2a}\hat{c}_{-k}^{(1)\dagger} \right) $$

He then takes these operators and plugs this into the following equation:

$$\large \hat{n}_R^{(1)}(k)=\hat{b}_k^{(1)\dagger}\hat{b}_k^{(1)} $$

After this, he proceeds to calculate the average number of observed particles:

\begin{align*}
\large \langle0_M|\hat{n}_R^{(1)}(k)|0_M\rangle&=\large \langle0_M|\hat{b}_k^{(1)\dagger}\hat{b}_k^{(1)}|0_M\rangle
\\&=\large \frac{1}{2\sinh\left(\dfrac{\pi\omega}{a}\right)}\langle0_M|e^{-\pi\omega/a}\hat{c}_{-k}^{(1)}\hat{c}_{-k}^{(1)\dagger}|0_M\rangle
\\&= \large \frac{e^{-\pi\omega/a}}{2\sinh\left(\dfrac{\pi\omega}{a}\right)}\delta(0)
\\&= \large \frac{1}{e^{2\pi\omega/a}-1}\delta(0)
\end{align*}

Now, I understand how to derive all the parts leading up to this calculation, including obtaining these operators. However, when performing the last calculation, I can expand the $\hat{b}$ in terms of the $\hat{c}$ operators and obtain $e^{\pi\omega/2a}\hat{c}_{k}^{(1)^\dagger}\hat{c}_{k}^{(1)}$ for the order of the operators. I do not understand why we are able to swap the order of the operators, swap the sign of the k, swap the sign in the exponential, but not swap the sign in the $\sinh\left(\frac{\pi\omega}{a}\right)$ term. I know that $\omega = |k|$, so if $k$ gets changed to $-k$, then there shouldn't be a change in sign in $\omega$. Even if there is a change in sign in $\omega$, then shouldn't one also have a $\sinh\left({-\frac{\pi\omega}{a}}\right)$ instead of $\sinh\left({\frac{\pi\omega}{a}}\right)$.
I guess this leads to my question, can some show me, explicitly, what is going on in this calculation, and why some signs can get swapped while others don't, and how the operators get swapped?

As you wrote, we have the operators
$$
{\hat{b}_k}^{(1)}~=~\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sinh\left(\frac{\pi\omega}{a}\right)}}\left(\mathrm{e}^{\pi\omega/(2a)}{\hat{c}_k}^{(1)}+\mathrm{e}^{-\pi\omega/(2a)}{{\hat{c}_{-k}}^{(2)}}^\dagger\right)\,,
$$
$$
{\hat{b}_k}^{(2)}~=~\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sinh\left(\frac{\pi\omega}{a}\right)}}\left(\mathrm{e}^{\pi\omega/(2a)}{\hat{c}_k}^{(2)}+\mathrm{e}^{-\pi\omega/(2a)}{{\hat{c}_{-k}}^{(1)}}^\dagger\right)\,.
$$
The number operator is given by ${\hat{n}_R}^{(1)}={{\hat{b}_k}^{(1)\dagger}}{{\hat{b}_k}^{(1)}}$. There are four terms in this expansion but only one will be nonzero.
Any term ending with $\hat{c}_\ell$ acting on the Minkowski vacuum ket will vanish. Any term starting with ${\hat{c}_\ell}^\dagger$ will act on the Minkowski vacuum bra and will vanish, where $\ell$ is some stand-in momentum for $\pm k$.
As such, only a term proportional to $\hat{c}_\ell{\hat{c}_\ell}^\dagger$ will remain. Performing the expansion, we need $\hat{c}_\ell$ from ${{\hat{b}_k}^{(1)\dagger}}$ and ${\hat{c}_\ell}^\dagger$ from ${{\hat{b}_k}^{(1)}}$.
The only nonzero contribution to this expectation value is therefore
$$
\frac{1}{2\sinh\left(\frac{\pi\omega}{a}\right)}\mathrm{e}^{-\pi\omega/(2a)}{\hat{c}_{-k}}^{(2)}\mathrm{e}^{-\pi\omega/(2a)}{\hat{c}_{-k}}^{(2)\dagger}~=~\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\pi\omega/a}}{2\sinh\left(\frac{\pi\omega}{a}\right)}{\hat{c}_{-k}}^{(2)}{\hat{c}_{-k}}^{(2)\dagger}\,.
$$
Let me know if you need anything else clarifying!

Thank you so much! I guess it was just a typo in the textbook then. The superscript there was a (1), but it makes more sense now for it to be a (2).
